# Kill sleeping process when starting new one

Tags: bash, subprocess, fork, supervisord

i have some Watcher.sh script running on a directory /foo/bar. When something happens in /foo/bar it starts another script (Updater.sh) which first sleeps for 30 seconds and then do stuff. The Watcher.sh script is managed by supervisor, which is configured to restart the script if it ends. So when there was a change in /foo/bar and the Updater.sh is started (in a subprocess), the Watcher script should end and get started again by supervisor. If there is a second change in /foo/bar the new Updater.sh script should end the first one and start again its 30 second sleep before doing stuff.

Watcher.sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Started inotifywait with $BASHPID ID"
inotifywait -q -e modify,move,create,delete /foo/bar

/updater.sh &
```

Updater.sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Start Update process $BASHPID"
FILE=/var/run/updater.pid
if test -f "$FILE" ; then
  kill -9 `cat /var/run/updater.pid`
  rm /var/run/updater.pid
fi

echo $BASHPID > /var/run/updater.pid
echo "Change in /foo/bar, reload soon"
sleep 30
supervisorctl reload
```

My problem is that it just don't happen. The Watcher.sh script is restarted, but the Updater.sh script is not killed at all. I checked the /var/run/updater.pid which is definitely set after the first change, but it just don't enter the if case and even when it does, it does not continue after the kill.

Would be great if somebody knows where i do something wrong, it should be simple right?..

EDIT 1:
Use the following code in the updater.sh to not listen on a pid file

```
if ps -ef | grep -vE "grep|$BASHPID" | grep updater | awk '{print $2}' ; then
  echo "Kill it"
  kill -9 `ps -ef | grep -vE "grep|$BASHPID" | grep updater | awk '{print $2}'`
fi
```

Comment: Try to check process existence via `ps` instead of file. `ps -ef | grep -vE "grep|$BASHPID" | grep updater | awk '{print $2}'`.

Comment: @samthegolden wouldn't that cause the updater to kill himself? i need updater 2 to kill updater 1

Comment: `grep -vE "grep|$BASHPID"` will exclude your own process and show the running one. (assuming $BASHPID contains your current PID)

Comment: @samthegolden Ah okay got it. Somehow the script does not enter the if block, i updated my question with the code. When i execute the if directly inside the console it works

Comment: Try this way: `pid = $(your_command); echo "PID: $pid";  if [ ! -z "pid" ]; then kill -9 "$pid"`

Comment: @samthegolden still i have the problem that it looks like he don't execute that code..

Comment: Does it echo the PID? if so, it surely executes the code!